# I should get back distance, duration and directions as result when i pass an intent with origin and destination in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-studio-3.0

I am working on an android application in which during the registration of the user i will get his location and i had a starting point.

- I am thinking of sending an intent to Google maps and getting back required result from it. How can i extract the distance, duration and directions from the result of intent?
- Is there any other way better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). It has many options like direction, distance (walking, driving etc). See example [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples).